# Как авторизоваться на сайте с помощью selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Не получатся авторизоваться на сайте, при отправке формы страница просто перезагружается. В чем проблема?

```
river = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = phantom_js_executable_path)
driver.get('site_url')
user_name = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
user_name.send_keys("****")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.send_keys("*****")
driver.find_element_by_name('continue').click()    
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("confirm"))        
    print(driver.title)
finally:
    print False
```

Comment: с фантома на визуальные если перейти, firefox, chromium, то данные все вводятся?

Comment: Да, все вводится. Я даже пробовал просто создать браузер и руками все вбить при нажатии также все сбрасывается. При чем если запустить браузер не в selenium то все работает.

Comment: Там не требуется ничего в стиле flash или java для авторизации?

Comment: Только js требуется.

Comment: Если версия PhantomJS 1.9, то он чутка глючный и есть смысл попробовать версию 2 (хотя она тоже глючная, но по-другому)

Comment: тогда только заголовок браузера, других вариантов не вижу

Comment: user agent имеется в виду?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй прописать максимум инфы в ЮзерАгент. Например:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
```